# Setting app icon in xcconfig file not working

Tags: xcode, xcconfig

I am trying to set different app icon sets for different schemes in Xcode (for an app exclusively for iOS). I have an xcconfig file for dev, test, and prod. In my `Development.xcconfig` I have the following.

```
ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME = AppIcon-dev
```

And correspondingly in the files for test and prod. In my assets folder I have the `AppIcon-dev` icon set etc. I have created build configuration for the different xcconfig files and have connected them to different schemes. But when I try building the project I get the follwing error.

```
error build: Command CompileAssetCatalog failed with a nonzero exit code
```

If I change the icon set name back to just `AppIcon`, the error goes away and I can build the project. Even though I still have the `ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME` variable set to `AppIcon-dev` in the xcconfig file (and I have activated the dev scheme).

Do I need to do anything else to get it to work with different icon sets? I know that I can set the icon set names for different build configuration under `Build Settings > Primary App Icon Set Name`, but then what is the point of having the xcconfig file if I need to define the icon set names in two different places?

To set up the xcconfig files, I followed this guide: https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/xcconfig_guide.html